# Not getting email from claims OpenIdConnect using Microsoft Identity when deployed to Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I am working on Web App web forms and used Microsoft Identity Authentication.  I am getting
User name and email address without an issue. But when I deployed the app to azure the getting email address throwing error.

```
            lblName.Text = System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("name").Value;
            
           lblAuthenticated IsAuthenticated = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
            lblAuthGroup.Text = System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("preferred_username").Value;

            var email = System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("preferred_username").Value;
```

I am getting all the values from claims when working in local but after deployment email is throwing error. I would like to mention that the error is not clear but here it is:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at Recertification_web.MainPage.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Projects\Repos\glo
```

Answer (score 0):

**In order to get email from claims openId connect, follow the below steps if helpful:**

- Try Including email scope in your authentication request.
- Make sure whether you have given delegated permissions like *Sign in* and *read user profile* for your application in azure AD

> **Not getting the e-mail address back could be caused due to the following issues:**

- **No e-mail address associated with the Azure AD account:**

Even if you are not getting the email address even after including the scope, please see below note:

> **Note** : The `email` claim is included in a token only if an email address is associated with the user account, which is not always the
> case. If it uses the `email` scope, your app should be prepared to
> handle a case in which the `email` claim does not exist in the token.

- **Claims discarded by middleware**

Try adding `Notifications` property to your `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions` object, like below:

```cs
 Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
    {
        AuthorizationCodeReceived = context =>
        {
            var claims = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.Claims;
            foreach (var claim in claims)
            {
                Log.Debug("{0} = {1}", claim.Type, claim.Value);
            }
            return null;
        }
```

For more in detail, please **refer** the below links:

[Ref1](https://newbedev.com/get-the-user-s-email-address-from-azure-ad-via-openid-connect), [Ref2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims), [Ref3](https://www.minitool.com/news/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object.html).